# Cannot declare an operator within a function. Clang bug or spec?

Tags: c++, clang, language-lawyer, infix-notation, name-lookup

One of the weirder corner cases of C is that functions can be declared within other functions, e.g.

```
void foo(void)
{
  void bar(void); // Behaves as if this was written above void foo(void)
  bar();
}
```

This has carried through into C++, at least for most functions. Clang doesn't appear to recognise the pattern if the function in question happens to be called operator==.

```
struct foo
{
  int value;
};

struct bar
{
  foo value;
};

bool wot(const bar &x, const bar &y)
{
  bool eq(const foo &, const foo &);         // Declare function eq
  bool operator==(const foo &, const foo &); // Declare function operator==
  bool func = eq(x.value, y.value);          // This line compiles fine
  bool call = operator==(x.value, y.value);  // Also OK - thanks user657267!
  bool op = x.value == y.value;              // This one doesn't
  return func && call && op;
}

bool test()
{
  bar a;
  bar b;
  return wot(a,b);
}
```

GCC and ICC compile this fine. Checking name mangling in the object suggests the operator== has been declared with the right types. Clang (I tried up to 3.8) errors:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression
      ('const foo' and 'const foo')
      bool op = x.value == y.value;
                ~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~
```

Unless the declaration is moved to directly above the function, in which case Clang is happy too:

```
bool operator==(const foo &, const foo &);
bool wot(const bar &x, const bar &y)
{
  return x.value == y.value; // fine
}
```

I can't use this workaround as the "real world" case that provoked this question involves layers of templates, meaning I only know the type name "foo" within the function declaration.

I believe this is a bug in Clang - is there special handling of operatorX free functions which prohibits declaring them within a function?

Comment: Seems to work fine using the explicit call `bool op = operator==(x.value, y.value);`, for whatever reason clang's operator lookup is failing to find the block scope declaration.

Comment: Very good spot! Thank you

Comment: [over.match.oper]/2 says that operator invocation `a@b` causes a non-member candidate `operator@(a,b)` before anything else happens , so the fact that the second form works but the first doesn't strongly suggests a bug

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For overloaded operators, see [[over.match.oper]/(3.2)](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3):

> […] for a binary operator `@` with a left operand of a type whose cv-unqualified version is `T1` and a right operand of a type whose
>   cv-unqualified version is `T2`, […] *non-member
>   candidates* […] are constructed as follows:
>
> **The set of non-member candidates is the result of the unqualified
>   lookup of `operator@` in the context of the expression according to the
>   usual rules for name lookup in unqualified function calls (3.4.2)
>   except that all member functions are ignored.** However, if no operand
>   has a class type, […]

That is, we have the exact same name lookup rules as in ordinary calls, because `x.value` is of class type (`foo`). It's a Clang bug, and it occurs with all binary operators. Filed as [#27027](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27027).

Answer (score 2):

It is true that C allows functions to be declared inside functions: 6.7.5.3 Function declarators §17 (draft n1256 for C99) says (emphasize mine)

> If the declaration occurs outside of any function, the identifiers have file scope and external linkage. **If the
>   declaration occurs inside a function**, the identifiers of the functions f and fip have block scope and either
>   internal or external linkage (depending on what file scope declarations for these identifiers are visible), and
>   the identifier of the pointer pfi has block scope and no linkage.

C++ also allows them. Draft n4296 for C++ 14 says:

> 13.2 Declaration matching [over.dcl] 
> ...
>   2 **A locally declared function** is not in the same scope as a function in a containing scope. [ Example:
>   void f(const char*);
>   void g() {
>   extern void f(int);
>   ...

(the above quote is only here to have an explicit evidence that C++ allows function declarations inside function)

I could even test that with your example this line:

```
bool op2 = operator == (x.value, y.value);
```

compiles fine without a single warning and gives expected results.

So I would say that it is a bug in Clang

Comment: What is the relevance of the 13.2 quote? In OP code there is no function of the same name in a containing scope anyway.

Comment: @M.M it was only to give an explicit evidence that C++ allows functions declaration inside functions.

Comment: OK. [basic.link]/6 and /7 actually describe the matching rules for block scope function declarations